OrderNumber not populating on email template for newly created Order
We have a newly built Flow that runs on Order creation or update, specifically on IsNew() or ISCHANGED(Status), to notify the customer when their Order has moved from one Status to another. Pretty basic stuff. All works perfectly except that the OrderNumber auto-number on the IsNew() Orders is not populating on the template, but it is for all of the others.
I've already confirmed that the field reference in the template is correct, the Flow is After-Save, and the User creating the Orders has access to Read the auto-number field.
Any ideas? I tried running the Flow in Async or with a 1 minute pause but it would throw an error with the same entry criteria I was using before.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
